# Can we have any OOB webpart in SharePoint in SharePoint 2010 same as SharePoint 2013 content search webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I need a web part in SharePoint 2010 that similar to SharePoint 2013 content search web part. We have any OOB webparts or custom webparts? Is is possible to develop that kind of web part in SharePoint 2010 using existing OOB webparts or custom web parts?

Comment: What kind of functionality from the content search web part do you want? The only OOB Webpart I can think of that does something similar is the Content By Query Web Part.

Answer (score 1):

The ContentByQueryWebPart, commonly referred to as the [Content Query Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx), is a part of the Enterprise Content Management (ECM) functionality in Microsoft Office SharePoint Server. It aggregates and displays list items within a site hierarchy.

The Content Query Web Part has the following limitations:

•You can only aggregate data within a single site collection.

•You can only aggregate list information.

You can also use SharePoint Designer to customize the aggregation and display capabilities of the Content Query Web Part with little or no coding

[To know more about Content Search Webpart Vs Content Query WebPart](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c69e0e45-8517-49ab-a004-bb2e251bcbad/content-search-webpart-vs-content-query-webpart?forum=sharepointgeneral)

[To know more about Content Query WebPart](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/05/14/what-s-new-with-the-content-query-web-part.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know about content query web part. i have worked with content query web part but i need  functionality similar to SharePoint 2013 content search web part. CQWP only have the options to crawl with in a site collection and missing so many options compare to CSWP.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, SharePoint 2010 OOTB only provides CQWP for your functionality.

Comment: If my above answer has provided required information, you can either upvote it or mark it as answer, so that it will be helpful to others.

Comment: Karthik, here iam just asking same to same webpart for Content search webparts in SharePoint 2010. I know that CQWP is some what sreaching that features. That is just about to 20% of fetures only it is having. My question is is there any similar webpart from OOB or Custom designed?